# How to hide UITableview cell and white space after hide it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to hide a cell from a UITableView. I know that UITableViewCell has a property called `hidden` but after hide I don't want white space. I want the boxes to be close together. I just want hide only condition result_id == nil || resuld_id == "" and hide a cell according to the condition

Func `cellForRowAt`

I already hide cell like this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! Static1vs1Cell
    let cellNoMatch = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseNoMatchIdentifier) as! NoMatchTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cellNoMatch.selectionStyle = .none
    cellNoMatch.backgroundColor = .clear
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if currentData.count == 0 {
            cellNoMatch.historyLabel.text = "No Match"
            return cellNoMatch
        }
        let ad: HistoryListModel = currentData[indexPath.row] as! HistoryListModel
        cell.setUI(md: ad, indexPath: indexPath, is_finish: false)
        
    }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if finishedData.count == 0 {
            cellNoMatch.historyLabel.text = "No Match"
            return cellNoMatch
        }
        let ad: HistoryListModel = finishedData[indexPath.row] as! HistoryListModel
        cell.setUI(md: ad, indexPath: indexPath, is_finish: true)
        if md.result_id == nil || md.result_id == ""{
            cell.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Func `heightForRowAt`

I set height = 0

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var rowHeight:CGFloat = 50
    if currentData.count > 0 {
        rowHeight = 95
    }
    else if finishedData.count > 0 {
        let ad: HistoryListModel = finishedData[indexPath.row] as! HistoryListModel
        if ad.result_id == nil || ad.result_id == "" {
            return 0.0
        }
        else{
            return 95
        }
    } else if finishedData.count == 0 {
        rowHeight = 50
    } else if currentData.count == 0 {
        rowHeight = 50
    }
    return rowHeight
}
```

[image]

Comment: `heightForRowAt` is a delegate method for the tableView. If you didn't set the delegate, that code will never be called.

Comment: @koen I already setup at Extension uitableviewdelegate and uitableviewdatasource

Answer (score 0):

For example, you need to filter the list of table elements and hide unnecessary.
Create a separate array for filtered items and update the table details.
Use it for table delegates.

NB. This solution requires additional memory, do not use it with a very large number of items.

```
var fullArray : [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        setFiltered()
    }
}

var filteredArray : [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData() // or use batch update
    }
}

let tableView = UITableView()

func setFiltered() {
    filteredArray = fullArray.filter({ $0 != "Hidden" })
}
```